# Excel formula to count the number of episodes someone is off sick

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this dataset below.
The first two rows contain weekday and date data, while rows 4 and 5 correspond to shift codes and absence codes, respectively. Shift codes can be 'E' or 'L' and absence code is 'SL' indicates sick leave.

Example 1:
[image]

Staff_1 has shifts booked from the 1st to the 5th, then on the 8th and 10th with absence codes on the 1st, 5th, 8th and 9th.

In this example, there are 2 episodes of sickness. The first episode starts on the 1st and goes still 2nd. The second episode starts on the 5th and continues as the same episode on the 8th and 10th, as there are no shifts booked in between this dates. So, the total number of episodes is 2.

Example 2:
[image]

Staff_2 has shift codes booked on the 1st, 2nd, 5th, 8th till the 10th.
The absence codes are present on the 1st, 2nd, 5th, 8th and 10th.
The first sick episode start on the 1st still the 2nd but continues on the 5th as there are no shifts booked in-between them, which continues as the same episode on the 8th for the same reason. However, the absence on the 10th marks the start of a new episode, as there is a shift booked in-between (9th) making the total number of episodes 2.

Example 3
[image]

Example 3:
Staff has shift codes booked from Mon-Fri on both weeks, 1st to 5th and 8th to 12th.
Absence codes on the 1st, marks the start of the episode. Absence on the 3rd marks the beginning of a new episode. Absence on the 5th starts another episode which continues as the same episode on the 8th. Absence on the 10th marks a new episode. Absence on the 12th marks yet another new episode. So, the total number of episodes is 5.

How can I achieve it using formula. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: A countifs() for E or L and SL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `FREQUENCY()` Function with `MAX()`:

[image]

---

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(
 IF(B4:O4&"|"&B5:O5="E|SL",COLUMN(B4:O4),""),
 IF(B4:O4&"|"&B5:O5<>"E|SL",COLUMN(B4:O4),"")
 ))
```

---

Edit: As per the new update from OP:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>P4</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Freq, SCAN(,B4:O4&B5:O5,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,IF((y="E")+(y="L"),"|",y)))),
     SUM(N(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(_Freq),"|",,1)<>"")))
```

---

Or, Instead of using `SUM()` at the end, one can use `COLUMNS()` but this will return an error if there is nothing to work on:

```
=LET(
     _Freq, SCAN(,B4:O4&B5:O5,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,IF((y="E")+(y="L"),"|",y)))),
     COLUMNS(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(_Freq),"|",,1)))
```

---

Comment: Hi Mayukh, thanks for the formula.

I tried it and at first it seemed to be working, but if I add a shift code on the 9th, which would mean, Staff_1 came back to work, and then it went off sick again next day, the number of episodes would be 3, but the formula still counts as 2.

In another test, based on the original shifts codes booked, if I remove the shifts on 3rd and 4th, which would mean Staff_1 went off sick and never returned to work. The formula still return 2 when it should return 1.

Comment: It is unclear now, so what is the logic, how do we understand the pattern you are looking for. Can you update your post with few more examples. From the present post it makes only sense that you were looking for a frequency of counts which is max continuous but it now seems different. If Shift codes are removed then there are no episodes at all, so in that respect why should it return 1 and not more than 1

Comment: Hi Mayukh, I have updated the post. Thanks for your help, it is amazing that you are getting close to a solution.

Comment: @RodFar Hi, I have updated the answer with the required solution.

Comment: Hi @Maykh, this is next level formula, it does exactly what I need. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @RodFar glad to know it worked and can we clear up the space here so it looks cleaner